# android - Application is not completely closed

Tags: android

It's very strange and it's making lots of problems for my application . suppose I've opened the application , I go through 3 or fives activities or I press home from drawer menu and some works like this , When I press the back button in my MainActivity file , it ask me to press again to close the app and after that , It close the app .

this is the code so far for closing the application :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

the problem is ,after it close the app , when I open the recent app in android phone , it shows my application and when I click on the application , it opens the app again but not from the MainActivity , it opens some where else that I've been before and I should press backbutton again and again to come to mainActivity and exit again , it could happens several times .

How can I solve this problem? How can I completely close the app and left nothing opens from it  ?

Comment: seems perfact just replace  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

I guess it should remove the app from recents and will create the new Application instance when app is entered from the launcher icon.

Just in case, you could also check if activity was launched from recents :

```
int flags = getActivity().getIntent().getFlags();       
if ((flags & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
    // The activity was launched from history
}
```